# onPerformSync() called multiple times

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

My application has a Sync Adapter created following the structure showed by the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.htm). The `onPerformSync()` method gets data from the internet and inserts it on the database with a bulk insert:

```
Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(rssItems.size());

for(RssItem rssItem : rssItems) {
    ContentValues newsValues = new ContentValues();
    // Get data from the remote server
    // Fill all the values
    newsValues.put(...);
    // Add the values to a vector, at the end a BulkInsert will be called
    cVVector.add(newsValues);
}
mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(NewsEntry.CONTENT_URI, cvArray);
```

The database has a IGNORE politic when deals with conflicts:

```
final String SQL_CREATE_NEWS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + NewsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                NewsEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                NewsEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_TITTLE + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
                NewsEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_CONTENT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                NewsEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                NewsEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_IMAGE + " TEXT, " +
                NewsEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                NewsEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_LINK + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "UNIQUE (" + NewsEntry.COLUMN_NEWS_TITTLE +") ON CONFLICT IGNORE"+
                " );";
```

And the Sync Adapter is configured to perform a sync every 86400 seconds

```
/**
 * Helper method to schedule the sync adapter periodic execution
 */
public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
    Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
    String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
        SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                setSyncAdapter(account, authority).build();
        ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
    } else {
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
                authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
    }
}
```

However, it is called continuously.

Answer (score 0):

onPerformSync() will be called only if it is forcefully called using "requestSync" api and once at the time of account creation with empty bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with the same problem and after all I found that I also called `ContentResolver.requestSync()` multiple times (before every `onPerformSync()`). In another words, `requestSync()` causes `onPerformSync()` call. That was my mistake and I should reconsider the logic.

Try to log `requestSync()` calls in your code and likely you are able to find the mistake.